# Python string formatting incremental changes

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

```
def foo(string, **kwargs):
  return string % kwargs  # simplified a much more complex SQL query function with argument binding.

string = '%(a)s %(b)s.'
print foo(string %{'a': 'Hello'}, b='world')
```

I want to achieve this '%(a)s %(b)s' => 'Hello %(b)s' => 'Hello world' (and not '%(a)s %(b)s' => 'Hello world' in one go).

Is there anyway in python to make it work?

Comment: The `%` operator is not officially deprecated but newer code is supposed to use the new string format spec [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: This is outside the scope of the question, but I have put the answer based on your comment below.

Comment: BTW, you may want to check sqlalchemy.sql - personally I find it better than interpolating strings. If not for the convenience, it is worth just for the portability and security (are you sure you are handling every injection technique out there?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just double the `%`:

```
string = '%(a)s %%(b)s.'
```

If you want to use the new string formatting spec, then you can similarly double the braces:

```
def foo(string, **kwargs):
  return string.format(**kwargs ) # simplified a much more complex SQL query function with argument binding.

string = '{a} {{b}}.'
print foo(string.format(a='Hello'), b='world')

prints: 
Hello world.
```